# How do you do data analysis on python? I'm doing a project on using statistics to find the winner of the NBA playoffs

Tags: python, analytics

How do you analyze statistics on python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and Pandas Python libraries are used for statistical analysis.

http://www.numpy.org/
https://pandas.pydata.org/